# Cant filter by field from include

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm having some issues trying to do a findAll method in sequelize and using the "include" option to do some inner joins and filter through the fields of the tables that i included.

I've tried to add a where option in the included object thinking that it would work like a normal where clause but it added the clause to the inner join

#### This is the code to simulate my tables

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_B(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_A(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    bId INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (bId) REFERENCES TABLE_B (id)
);
```

### This is an example of the sequelize method and the basic query it's executing

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

const Op = Sequelize.Op;

function randomMethod(keyWord) {
    return table_a.findAll({
        where: {
            name: {
                [Op.or]: [{ [Op.like]: '%' + keyWord + '%' }, null],
            }
        },
        include: [{
            model: table_b,
            required: true,
            as: "table_b",
        }]
    })
}
```

It basically executes a query like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    * 
FROM table_a 
    INNER JOIN table_b 
        ON table_a.bId = table_b.id 
WHERE 
    table_a.name like '%'|| KeyWord ||'%' OR table_a = NULL;
```

## This is an example of the query I'm tryng to do on sequelize

```sql
SELECT 
    * 
FROM table_a 
    INNER JOIN table_b 
        ON table_a.bId = table_b.id 
WHERE 
    (table_a.name like '%'|| KeyWord ||'%' OR table_a = NULL)
        OR
    table_b.name like '%'|| KeyWord ||'%';
```

But I can't seem to find a way of doing it with sequelize and I didn't find anybody with a question resembling this one. Can anybody help me?